# Applying Transformation to Table (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

I have the following data frame

```
Index ID    Wt    Wt.1
0     4999  3.2   1.2
1     5012  1.1   3.4
2     5027  4.4   5.6
```

and I'm trying to apply a transformation in order to get a dataframe that looks like the following

```
Index ID    Wt 
0     4999  3.2
0     4999  1.2
1     5012  1.1
1     5012  3.4
2     5027  4.4
2     5027  5.6
```

Is there a simply way to do this? I have tried using melt, groupby, and pivot_table but with no luck.  This seems like such a simple task so perhaps I am overthinking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to assign to an empty dataframe the 'ID' and 'Wt.1' columns to the empty dataframe as the target 'ID' and 'Wt' columns, this has a minor advantage in that you don't get a messy append at the end where you have `NaN` values and both 'Wt' and 'Wt.1' columns.

```
In [28]:

temp = pd.DataFrame()
temp[['ID','Wt']] = df[['ID','Wt.1']]
df1 = df[['ID','Wt']].append(temp)

df1
Out[28]:
         ID   Wt
Index           
0      4999  3.2
1      5012  1.1
2      5027  4.4
0      4999  1.2
1      5012  3.4
2      5027  5.6

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can call `df1.reset_index(inplace=True)` to correct the index afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it in few lines, but I will show them step-by-step:

```
In [86]:

df2=df.set_index(['Index', 'ID'])
df3=df2.stack().reset_index()
df3=df3.ix[:,['Index', 'ID', 0]]
df3.columns=['Index', 'ID', 'Wt']
print df3
   Index    ID   Wt
0      0  4999  3.2
1      0  4999  1.2
2      1  5012  1.1
3      1  5012  3.4
4      2  5027  4.4
5      2  5027  5.6
```